# Can JavaScript DOM api get the original casing of attribute & tag names?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there any way to get access to the original (from source) casing of an attribute name or tag name?

- attribute.name is lowercased
- element.tagName is uppercased
- element.localName is lowercased

I'm hoping for a non-XHTML solution, because XML makes me sad ☹ .  And I can't require that level of validity from the users...

Comment: While this is a good question, I'm curious: Why would you need to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way: use XHTML<sup>(*)</sup>.

According to [`element.tagName` article MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.tagName),

> In XML (and XML-based languages such as XHTML), `tagName` preserves
>   case.

Currently there is no [`Attr.name` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Attr.name), but in my tests it also preserves case in XHTML.

<sub>(*) I mean you must serve the page as XHTML, just using a XHTML doctype isn't enough.</sub>

**Caveat**: In XHTML, `<span>` and `<sPaN>` are different. That means that:

- `span {}` CSS selector won't affect `<sPaN>`
- `document.getElementsByTagName('span')` won't include `<sPaN>`
- `document.querySelectorAll('span')` won't include `<sPaN>`
- `document.createElement('sPaN')` gives an instance of `HTMLUnknownElement` instead of `HTMLSpanElement`.

And of course, if you attempt to validate the page, it will be invalid XHTML. But browsers will parse it well (no draconian error).

Comment: That's odd.  I thought, due to xhtml being case sensitive, you were required to use lowercase for both tag and attribute names.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yes, if you attempt to [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) it, it will be invalid. But browsers will parse it well (no draconian error). On Firefox and Chrome at least.